# Error al establecer un nuevo saldo en una cuenta con arreglos y acumuladores

Tags: java

Disculpen pero soy nuevo en Java, el asunto es que tengo que hacer un programa de sistema bancario.

En este programa pensé que tenía que usar Arreglos porque si lo hacía sin ellos al crear un nuevo usuario se eliminaría el anterior.

El programa pide Nombre, Apellido, DPI, teléfono y Saldo.

***En el Main Principal es donde se encuentra el error***, en la opción 1 es donde se crea el usuario y pide un saldo inicial, luego en la opción 3 se debe de buscar a ese usuario y poderle depositar a la misma cuenta con la que inició en la opción 1.

Para ello pensé usar un acumulador pero aquí es donde está el problema.

> ***cannot find symbol:***
>   nuevaCuenta[i] = ***OperacionesFondo***(saldoC);

Aquí esta el código:

```
@author User
 */
public class OperacionesFondo {
   private String nombreC, apellidoC;
   private Float saldoC;
   private int dpiC, telefonoC, contador=0, i=0;

   /*ESTABLECER LOS METODOS SETTER Y GETTER PARA NOMBRE*/

    public OperacionesFondo (String nombre,String apellido, int telefono, int dpi, Float dinero) {
            this.nombreC = nombre;
            this.apellidoC = apellido;
            this.telefonoC =  telefono;
            this.dpiC =  dpi;

            do {
                if (dinero>75){     
            this.saldoC = this.saldoC + dinero;
    }
        else {
                System.out.println("El monto debe ser mayor a Q75");
             } 

        }while (dinero<=75);

        }


    public String getNomCuenta()
    {
        return this.nombreC;
    }

    public String getApeCuenta()
    {
        return this.apellidoC;
    }

        public int getTel()
    {
        return this.telefonoC;
    }

    public int getDpi()
    {
        return this.dpiC;
    }

        public float getSaldo()
    {
                return this.saldoC;
    }



}





import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class Cuenta {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    /*VARIABLES Y CLASES GLOBALES*/
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
       OperacionesFondo[] nuevaCuenta  = new OperacionesFondo [100] ;
         int opc;
         String nombreC, apellidoC;
         Float saldoC;
         int dpiC, telefonoC, array=0, busqueda, confirmacion;

    /*-------------------------------------------------*/  
        do {
        System.out.println("Menú de opciones: Operaciones Bancarias");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("1. Aperturar nueva cuenta: ");
        System.out.println("2. Consultar saldo actual");
        System.out.println("3. Depósito a cuenta");
    System.out.println("4. Retiro de cuenta");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");        
    System.out.println("Seleccione una opción para comenzar: ");

        opc=teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();

        if (opc==1){

                for (int i=0; i<nuevaCuenta.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del Usuario");
            nombreC = teclado.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese apellido del Usuario");
            apellidoC = teclado.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese teléfono del Usuario");
            telefonoC = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese DPI del Usuario");
            dpiC = teclado.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de Saldo Inicial, debe de proceder con un mínimo de Q76.00 ");
            saldoC = teclado.nextFloat();

            nuevaCuenta[i] = new OperacionesFondo (nombreC, apellidoC, telefonoC,  dpiC,  saldoC);
            teclado.nextLine();

            array=array+1;
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            System.out.println("Felicidades "+nuevaCuenta[i].getNomCuenta()+", su cuenta ha sido creada con éxito, su número de cuenta es: "+array);
            }

            }

        else if (opc==2) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese Numero del Usuario");
            busqueda = teclado.nextInt();

               for (int i=0; i<nuevaCuenta.length; i++) {
                   do {
                   if (busqueda==i){
                  System.out.println(nuevaCuenta[i].getNomCuenta()+"--"+nuevaCuenta[i].getApeCuenta()+"--"+nuevaCuenta[i].getTel()+"--"+nuevaCuenta[i].getDpi()+"--"+nuevaCuenta[i].getSaldo()+"--");
                    }
                   else {
                    System.out.println("El usuario no existe");
                   }
                  } while (busqueda!=i);
              }
        }

        else if (opc==3) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese Numero del Usuario");
            busqueda = teclado.nextInt();

            for (int i=0; i<nuevaCuenta.length; i++) {

                   if (busqueda==i){
                       System.out.println("Numero de Cuenta: "+array);
                       System.out.println("¿Confirma el depósito? ");
                       System.out.println("Sí, presione 1"+ "No, presione 2");
                       confirmacion = teclado.nextInt();
                       if (confirmacion==1) {

                        System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de Saldo a depositar: ");
                        saldoC = teclado.nextFloat();
                        teclado.nextFloat();
                        nuevaCuenta[i] = OperacionesFondo(saldoC);


                        }
                        else {
                        System.out.println("El usuario no existe");
                   } 


                       }
                   else {
                        System.out.println("El usuario no existe");
                   } 

                  } 



        }



        } while (opc!=5);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes:

```
nuevaCuenta[i] = OperacionesFondo(saldoC);
```

estás:

- Usando un constructor como si fuera un método estático
- Si pones `new` para usarlo propiamente, seguirá mostrando error porque sólo tienes un constructor declarado y recibe múltiples parámetros, mientras que sólo le estás pasando uno en esa llamada.

Comment: Entonces que podría hacer para que funcione correctamente?